# Interrupted partition aligning and disk corrupted

Tags: partitioning, ntfs, partition-recovery, mft

So, I was resizing my partition and accidentally aligned it to the left. I didn't noticed it and it successfully resized it. Then it started to align the partition and I was thinking this was some sort of a bug and stopped it, ignoring the warning. (yeah i'm so dumb) Now the partition is broken and I don't know what to do and **I don't want to format it**.

Maybe it can be fixed by somehow moving it back? Thanks.

**UPD:** CHKDSK says that MFT is corrupted, so I guess I need to fix the MFT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've already acknowledged that it wasn't smart to ignore the warning, so I won't belabour that point (though I certainly agree with your assessment).

The easiest thing to do would be to create a new partition at the proper location and restore your files from a backup. However, I'm assuming that "I don't want to format it" means "I don't have a backup".

In that case, it will likely take hours of work to repair, even if you happen to know the exact offset where the process stopped. The beginning of an NTFS filesystem tends to contain some of the most important information, including the Master File Table (MFT). There is a second copy of the MFT on the disk, but there is a high likelihood that any files that had fragments in the moved section of the disk will be irretrievable, if you can mount the filesystem at all.

If you choose to go ahead and attempt a recovery, you should **take an image of the drive before running any tool that writes to the drive**. This includes `chkdsk` with the `/f` flag. This will ensure that you can always revert to the "least-broken" version of your drive.

If `chkdsk` is able to repair your drive to a state where it can be mounted, it is unlikely that it will be bootable (if it is a boot drive). In this case, you may be able to boot another operating system, mount the drive, and recover some of your files.

If you're able to ascertain where the move process left off, you may be able to reverse the process: however, this will almost certainly involve writing custom code to shift the data back.

Good luck. Please remember to back up your important data to avoid problems like this in the future.

Comment: Thank you. In the end I used DMDE to recover at least _some_ files and formatted the drive. I will make a backup this time. :)